# setting a border to an element inside the div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have a div element

```
 <div class="ImageArea"
          onClick={(e)=>onClickBox(e,_.id)}
          style={{
          width: "calc(52.9% - 12px)", height: "calc(46% - 7px)", bottom: "6.68%", left: "108.5%" }
          }}
```

overflow:'scroll'
>

```
          {boxes.map((item,index) => {
          if(item.boxId === _.id&& item.index===(initTab||galleyIndex)){
          return (<>
             <div className='galley_box flexCol' key={index}>
         { showCartDesign(item.cartQuantityAllots,_.id)}
          </div>
```

the showCartDesign function is,

```
const showCartDesign=(crt,id)=>{
        if(crt.length){
          const cartStat=crt.map(c=>(<>
      <div className="cart-display">
       <div className="flexRow" style={{padding:'0.5rem'}}>
      <b  className='cart-title'>{c.code}</b>
      <u className="cart-type">{getCartType(c.cartType)}</u>
      <img className="galley-icons" src={plus}  onClick={(e)=>onClickAddCart(e,id)} alt='GalleyAdd'/><img className="galley-icons" src={minus}  onClick={(e)=>onClickRemoveCart(e,id,c.code)} alt='GalleyRemove'/><img className="galley-icons" src={editGalleyItem} onClick={(e)=>onClickEditCart(e,id,c.code)} alt='GalleyEdit'/><br/>
      </div>
      {getTrolleyItems(c,id)}
      </div>

      </>))
      return cartStat
        }

      }

      const getTrolleyItems=(tr,id)=>{
      if(tr){
      const listItems =
      tr.typesOfItems?.map((i,index) => (
      <li className="box-items" key={index}>{i.name}</li>
      ))
      const count=listItems?.length>1?'items':'item'
      return (<><div className="list-items" style={{lineHeight:'1.5rem',color:"#ffffff",display:'flex',fontWeight:'bold',margin:'0.5rem 0rem 0.5rem 0rem',justifyContent:'center'}}>{`${listItems?.length} ${count}`}</div>
      <ul className="galley-list">{listItems}</ul>
      </>
      );
      }


      }
```

the css used are,

```
.cart-display{
  border:0.3px solid grey;
 background-color:#1d3e4e;
  margin-top:0.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px
}
.cart-label{
  outline:1px solid;
  padding:3px;
  top: 5;
  z-index: 1;
  position:'sticky';
  background-color:'#bebebe'
}
.cart-title{

    outline: 1px solid;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #bebebe;

}

.cart-type{
    outline: none;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #bebebe;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.box-items{
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  list-style-type: circle;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;}
```

in the .cartDisplay class i am using a border property but it only takes the width of the class having div 'ImageArea' ,hence  it appears only giving border to the div which is visible inside the main div and not while scrolling.is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You can use a descendant selector. Something like `.class-target > div` (the first child of the class-target class), or `class-target div` which is *any* descendant of the class-target class.

Comment: Questions about CSS should include HTML, not application code (JSX). Please simplify your example in a demo snippet using the editor.